How Can I Create Setup File With All Administor Permissions?
I can't run a program that i made with python, i have to use "run as administor" option.
I made a program that uses SQLLite3 with python. Then I wanted to convert it a setup file. I used Inno Setup Compiler and here the codes:
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "3K"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Marjinal"
#define MyAppExeName "main.exe"
#define MyAppAssocName MyAppName + " File"
#define MyAppAssocExt ".myp"
#define MyAppAssocKey StringChange(MyAppAssocName, " ", "") + MyAppAssocExt

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{2D6F5BA8-84E2-4205-BC2A-377A520840E1}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
ChangesAssociations=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
InfoBeforeFile=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\My App\before installation.txt
InfoAfterFile=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\My App\after installation.txt
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\Output
OutputBaseFilename=3K Setup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\My App\Marjinal.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "turkish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Turkish.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\My App\{#MyAppExeName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\My App\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\myapp.exe.manifest"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExt}\OpenWithProgids"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueData: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppAssocName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1"""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\{#MyAppExeName}\SupportedTypes"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".myp"; ValueData: ""

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent



When i start the program by clicking run as administor button, it works. Otherwise it doesn't work and throw an error like 'sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file'.
I want to start this program with all administrator permission. Should i add a manifest file, if it is then how? if it is not what i should do ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
